# ASP Classic - Find last weeks Friday or any day using days as numbers (1-7, 1=Monday and so on..)

Tags: asp-classic

I would like to find last weeks Friday for example.
Using days as numbers (1 through 7) for example:

```
1= Monday and so on..
```

It would be something like this but I'm stuck at the GetLastWeek, Please see below, THANKS.

```
<%
dim weeknum
weeknum=5

dim GetLastWeek
GetLastWeek=???? <== FIND LAST WEEKS FRIDAY AS A DATE Eg: MM/DD/YYYY
%>

Example: Last weeks Friday was on: <%=GetLastWeek%>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I probably start by working out what is the current day of the week and working back from there, you can use something like this;

```vb
Dim today, offsetdays, lastfri
'WeekDay() returns 1 - 7 (Sunday - Saturday).
today = WeekDay(Date())

'Workout the offset then use DateAdd() to minus that number of days.
Select Case today
Case 1 'Sunday
  offsetdays = 2
Case 2 'Monday
  offsetdays = 3
Case 3 'Tuesday
  offsetdays = 4
Case 4 'Wednesday
  offsetdays = 5
Case 5 'Thursday
  offsetdays = 6
Case 6 'Friday
  offsetdays = 7
Case 7 'Saturday
  offsetdays = 1
End Select

lastfri = DateAdd("d", -offsetdays, Date())
```

---

Bear in mind this is pseudo coded (untested) and could probably be made better by storing the offsets in an array and using that to power the `DateAdd()` instead.

Comment: As you asked the question again this is the better solution - http://stackoverflow.com/a/24520408/692942 It uses `Mod()` which is more flexible approach to dealing with different days as the input.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Weekday()` function to find what day of the week any particular date is. With this you should be able to calculate anything else you like. There is a full reference for the function here:

http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_weekday.asp