# ASP Classic - Get last weeks date by day number

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, vb6

**For example:** What was the Date (***format: MM/DD/YYYY***) for 1? and the answer would be: ***6/30/2014***

Day number works like this:

```
Monday=1
...
Friday=5
Sunday=7
```

So something like this:

```
<%
   dim GetPastDay
   GetPastDay=1  
  '^ ^ ^ THIS WOULD MEAN THAT WE ARE LOOKING TO GET PAST/LAST MONDAYS DATE 
  ' AND IF WE WHERE TO REPLACE THE 1 WITH A 5 THEN IT WOULD MEAN PAST/LAST FRIDAY.

   dim GetPastDate
   '** S.O.S. -> I'M STUCK HERE! <- **
%>
```

**THE FINAL OUTPUT WOULD BE:**

```
<%
   Response.write "Last Date for day: " & GetPastDay & " was Date: " & GetPastDate
%>
```

Comment: You've [already asked this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24499453/asp-classic-find-last-weeks-friday-or-any-day-using-days-as-numbers-1-7-1-mo) not long ago...

Comment: @Paul Similar, but I'm with you. Not sure it needed another question asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
' Test each possible entry from Monday (1) to Sunday (7)...
For i = 1 To 7

    ' Calculate the number of days to subtract from today's date...
    j = (8 - i) Mod 7 + 1

    ' Get the date...
    d = Date - j

    ' Display the date and the weekday...
    MsgBox "Date: " & d & vbCrLf & "Day: " & WeekDayName(WeekDay(d))

Next
```

Comment: Nice approach using `Mod()`, it is an under used and versatile function.